# I am trying to enter my domian in the App Domains field on facebook developers page and I keep getting: Site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook

My site url is podium.za.com, it keeps giving me the error: Site URL is not a valid URL.Is this something to do with the .za.com? I have been trying to get this working for days now.

Comment: Did you check to see if your domain is blacklisted? http://uribl.com/

Comment: it seems like all .za.com domains do not work in Facebook, I tested a .uk.com and works fine, how would I notify facebook of this issue?

Comment: You can file a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs), but don't hold your breath. It may be something like your DNS system is spammy. You'll probably get this resolved quicker if you pay to have your domain whitelisted.